# Align legend text in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have difficulty in aligning the legend text to the left.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
o3<- rnorm(1827, 50, 10)
NO2<- rnorm(1827, 35, 7)
NOx<- rnorm(1827, 45, 10)
pm25<- rnorm(1827, 15, 4)
date<-seq(as.Date('2000-01-01'),as.Date('2004-12-31'),by = 1)
df<-data.frame(date,o3,NO2,NOx,pm25)
meltdf <- melt(df,id="date")
```

With this code the alignment is automatically to the left

```
ggplot(meltdf, aes(x = date, y = value, colour =variable)) + geom_smooth() + stat_smooth(method = "gam")
```

However with the following the alignemt is to the centre.

```
ggplot(meltdf, aes(x = date, y = value, colour =variable)) + 
      geom_smooth() + stat_smooth(method = "gam") +
      scale_color_discrete(name="Pollutant" ,labels = c(expression(O[3]),
                                expression(NO[2]),
                                expression(NO[x]),
                                expression(PM[2.5])))
```

How could I achieve left alignment with the last script?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to specify `legend.text.align` in `theme()`:

```
ggplot(meltdf, aes(x = date, y = value, colour =variable)) + 
geom_smooth() + 
stat_smooth(method = "gam") +
scale_color_discrete(name="Pollutant", 
    labels = c(expression(O[3]),
               expression(NO[2]),
               expression(NO[x]),
               expression(PM[2.5]))) +
theme(legend.text.align = 0)
```

[image]

Alternatively, try using `bquote` instead of `expression`, and default left alignment takes place. I don't know why just using `expression` changes the alignment to the right...

```
ggplot(meltdf, aes(x = date, y = value, colour =variable)) + 
geom_smooth() + 
stat_smooth(method = "gam") +
scale_color_discrete(name="Pollutant", 
    labels = c(bquote(O[3]),
               bquote(NO[2]),
               bquote(NO[x]),
               bquote(PM[2.5])))
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I assume the default must be left align as the first code automatically created left aligned legend. Why did the second script resulted in centred/right aligned output? In which situations do I need to add "theme(legend.text.align = 0)"?

Comment: Well the short answer would be whenever the text is not aligned to the left :) I don't know why in this case the alignment is not to the left, which is the default. The reason your script results in right-aligned output has to do with the use of expressions, if you use bquote instead the default left alignment is used -see update