# How to italicize one category in a legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, italics, ggtext

For my legend in ggplot2 I have 2 categories, how do I italicize only 1 category and not the other?

As an example, consider the following plot. How can I set "Manual" in italics?

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = as.factor(am), fill = as.factor(am))) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  scale_fill_discrete(
    "Transmission",
    breaks = c(0, 1),
    labels = c("Automatic", "Manual")
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 18):

You can use `expression` and `italic` to create italicized text on labels.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = as.factor(am), fill = as.factor(am))) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  scale_fill_discrete(
    "Transmission",
    breaks = c(0, 1),
    labels = c("Automatic", expression(italic("Manual")))
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Really helpful response r.bot, thanks for posting! Just wanted to note if you're looking to get both legend entries aligned left you can add the following: ``+ theme(legend.text.align = 0)``. See this entry for more about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26781676/align-legend-text-in-ggplot

Answer (score 14):

I have been working on a simpler and more flexible way to achieve this goal, via the ggtext package that enables markdown styling in ggplot. This is currently under development but should be released to CRAN soon (early 2020).

```r
library(ggplot2) # may require: remotes::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")
library(ggtext)  # remotes::install_github("clauswilke/ggtext")

ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = as.factor(am), fill = as.factor(am))) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  scale_fill_discrete(
    "Transmission",
    breaks = c(0, 1),
    labels = c("Automatic", "*Manual*")
  ) +
  theme(legend.text = element_markdown())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This works great, very simple.