# Overwrite ggplot axis labels with Latex expressions

Tags: r, ggplot2, latex, axis-labels

How can I overwrite the axis text (the text of the connected to the tix, not the axis title) with a latex expression which is evaluated/printed through [`latex2exp` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/latex2exp/vignettes/using-latex2exp.html)?

The usual way of renaming axis text does not work:

**MWE**

```
df <- data.frame(x=c("a","b"), y=c(1,2))
ggplot(df, aes(x, y))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c(TeX("$Test^{89}$"), TeX("$Oh_{i,j}^{99}$")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found out - it is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62263848/ggplot-legend-label-with-latex-expression-variable-value-normal-text). Basically, you need to wrap `unname()` around it.

```
df <- data.frame(x=c("a","b"), y=c(1,2))
ggplot(df, aes(x, y))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=unname(TeX(
    c("$Test^{89}$","$Oh_{i,j}^{99}$"))))
```